# ondragover equivalent in Vue.Draggable (sortable.js)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, sortablejs

Is there a way to detect if something is being dragged over an element? Or trigger the hover event? Found something about adding a class to the dragged over element via onMove, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: What was the `onMove` solution and in what way did it not work for you?

Comment: I looked at it after posting that and it was apparently to track what *sortable* element was being dragged over, which explains why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made a JSBin with a solution: https://jsbin.com/xuwocis/edit?html,js,output

```
var sorting = false;

new Sortable(el, {
    onStart: function() {
        sorting = true;
    },
    onEnd: function() {
      sorting = false;
      // remove styling
      targetElement.style.backgroundColor = '';
    },
//     forceFallback:true
});

// For native drag&drop
targetElement.addEventListener('dragover', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});

targetElement.addEventListener('dragenter', function(evt) {
    if (sorting && !targetElement.contains(evt.relatedTarget)) {
        // Here is where you add the styling of targetElement
        targetElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
});

targetElement.addEventListener('dragleave', function(evt) {
    if (sorting && !targetElement.contains(evt.relatedTarget)) {
        // Here is where you remove the styling of targetElement
        targetElement.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
});


// For fallback
targetElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(evt) {
  if (sorting) {
    // Here is where you change the styling of targetElement
    targetElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
});

targetElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(evt) {
  if (sorting) {
    // Here is where you remove the styling of targetElement
    targetElement.style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
});

el.addEventListener('touchmove', function(evt) {
  if (!sorting) { return; }
  var x = evt.touches[0].clientX;
  var y = evt.touches[0].clientY;
  var elementAtTouchPoint = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  if (elementAtTouchPoint === targetElement ||
      // In case of a ghost element, the element at touch point
      // is the ghost element and thus we need to check if the parent 
      // of the ghost element is the targetElement.
      elementAtTouchPoint.parentNode === targetElement) {
    targetElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  } else {
    // Here is where you remove the styling of targetElement
    targetElement.style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
});
```

Basically, if Sorting with SortableJS, you do mouseenter & mouseleave events for the fallback, and dragenter & dragleave events (ignore bubbles) for native drag&drop. You will want both if you do not have `forceFallback: true`.

Comment: @Owen M have you found any examples of something like this working with the JQuery Sortable widget?

Comment: @ModusPwnens The same code should work, just pass the options to the jQuery-SortableJS function instead of to Sortable

Comment: @OwenM but then I lose sortable on my list. I have 2 lists, both should be sortable within themselves. When I drag an item from list 2 into list 1, it should push that item to a separate list. That separate list is built but is not visible on the screen. Really I want to be able to fire the dragenter event on a sortable element, but I don't know if that can be done.

Comment: Maybe I should just use SortableJS.